# In search getting details as table format using a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, backend

In one application I created a search page for employee where I will search employee with name, rank and location. Along with this three I added one dropdown menu in another which is named as advance search. in that dropdown there are some other options are included which employee is having. So when you search a employee name, rank and location and selecting one option in advance search I have to get that employee details which is selected in that option in a table format. for example I entered name rank and location a I selected courses as a option in advance search then I should get that specific employee courses details as a table format.
here i added the code part of advance search model for some options and api to fetch the data from backend

```js
const fetchPunishmentDetails = async () => {
        let mainSearch = {
            mainRank: searchData.rank,
            mainName: searchData.name,
            mainLocation: searchData.location,
          };
          setToken('empViewToken')
        const res = API.post(`/search_block/advanceSearchFilter?selectedOption=${selectedOption}`,{ mainSearch, filterType, advanceSearchData});
        // const data = await res.json();
        // setPunishmentSearch(data);
        return res;
    };
    const handleAdvancedSearch = async () => {
        const punishmentData = await fetchPunishmentDetails();
        console.log("selected_option", selectedOption)
        if (selectedOption === 'punishment') {
            setEmpView(false);
            const punishmentData = await fetchPunishmentDetails(searchQuery);
            setPunishmentSearch(punishmentData);
        } else if (selectedOption === 'courses') {
            const coursesData = await fetchCoursesDetails(searchQuery);
            setCoursesSearch(coursesData);
            // Handle other tables accordingly
        }
    };

    // useEffect hook to fetch the punishment data initially
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            if (searchQuery) {
                const punishmentData = await fetchPunishmentDetails(searchQuery);
                setPunishmentSearch(punishmentData);
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, [searchQuery]);

    const fetchCoursesDetails = async () => {
        const res = await fetch(`/search_block/advanceSearchFilter?selectedOption=${searchQuery}`);
        // const data = await res.json();
        // setCoursesSearch(data);
        return res;
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            if (searchQuery) {
                const coursesData = await fetchCoursesDetails(searchQuery);
                setCoursesSearch(coursesData);
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, [searchQuery]);

    const handleOptionChange = (e) => {
        setSelectedOption(e.target.value);
        setFilterType(e.target.value)
    };

    const handleAdvanceSearchData = (event) => {
        setAdvanceSearchData({ ...advanceSearchData, [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
    }
    
<Modal.Body>
            <form onSubmit={(e) => handleAdvanceSearch(e)}>
                        <div className="m-1">
                            <label htmlFor="search_by" className="form-label">SEARCH BY</label>
                            <select className='form-select form-select-sm' value={selectedOption} onChange={(e) => handleOptionChange(e)}  >
                                {
                                    searchTypes.map((item, index) => {
                                        return <option key={index} value={item.value}>{item.name}</option>
                                    })
                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        {selectedOption === 'personalDetails' &&
                            (<fieldset>
                                <div className="m-1"> PersonalDetails
                                    <br />
                                    <label htmlFor="no" className="form-label">No</label>
                                    <input id="no" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="no" type="number" value={advanceSearchData.name} onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="m-1">
                                    <label htmlFor="rank" className="form-label">Rank</label>
                                    <input id="rank" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="rank" type="text" value={advanceSearchData.rank} onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="m-1">
                                    <label htmlFor="trade" className="form-label">Trade</label>
                                    <input id="trade" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="trade" type="text" value={advanceSearchData.trade} onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="m-1">
                                    <label htmlFor="coy_pl" className="form-label">COY/PL</label>
                                    <input id="coy_pl" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="coy_pl" type="text" value={advanceSearchData.part2} onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="m-1">
                                    <label htmlFor="dob" className="form-label">Date Of Birth</label>
                                    <input id="dob" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="dob" type="date" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="m-1">
                                    <label htmlFor="doe" className="form-label">Date Of Employement</label>
                                    <input id="doe" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="doe" type="date" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="m-1">
                                    <label htmlFor="dom" className="form-label">Date Of Marriage</label>
                                    <input id="dom" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="dom" type="date" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="m-1">
                                    <label htmlFor="spouse_name" className="form-label">Name Of Spouse</label>
                                    <input id="spouse_name" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="spouse_name" type="text" value={advanceSearchData.age} onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="m-1">
                                    <label htmlFor="father_name" className="form-label">Name Of Father</label>
                                    <input id="father_name" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="father_name" type="text" value={advanceSearchData.occupation} onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="m-1">
                                    <label htmlFor="mother_name" className="form-label">Name Of Mother</label>
                                    <input id="mother_name" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="mother_name" type="text" value={advanceSearchData.qualification} onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="m-1">
                                    <label htmlFor="aadhar_card" className="form-label">Unique Identification Number(Aadhar)</label>
                                    <input id="aadhar_card" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="aadhar_card" type="number" value={advanceSearchData.age} onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="m-1">
                                    <label htmlFor="pan_card" className="form-label">Pan Card</label>
                                    <input id="pan_card" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="pan_card" type="text" value={advanceSearchData.occupation} onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="m-1">
                                    <label htmlFor="email_id" className="form-label">Email Id</label>
                                    <input id="email_id" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="email_id" type="text" value={advanceSearchData.qualification} onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="m-1">
                                    <label htmlFor="name_of_buddy" className="form-label">Name of Buddy</label>
                                    <input id="name_of_buddy" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="name_of_buddy" type="text" value={advanceSearchData.age} onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="m-1">
                                    <label htmlFor="mobile" className="form-label">Mobile Number</label>
                                    <input id="mobile" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="mobile" type="number" value={advanceSearchData.age} onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="m-1">
                                    <label htmlFor="address" className="form-label">Address</label>
                                    <textarea id="address" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="address" type="text" value={advanceSearchData.address} onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} col={5} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="m-1">
                                    <label htmlFor="city" className="form-label">City</label>
                                    <input id="city" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="city" type="text" value={advanceSearchData.age} onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="m-1">
                                    <label htmlFor="state" className="form-label">State</label>
                                    <input id="state" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="state" type="text" value={advanceSearchData.age} onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="m-1">
                                    <label htmlFor="country" className="form-label">Country</label>
                                    <input id="country" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="country" type="text" value={advanceSearchData.age} onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="m-1">
                                    <label htmlFor="pincode" className="form-label">Pin Code</label>
                                    <input id="pincode" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="pincode" type="number" value={advanceSearchData.age} onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="m-1">
                                    <label htmlFor="addl_special" className="form-label">Add Specialization(Trade Related)</label>
                                    <input id="addl_special" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="addl_special" type="text" value={advanceSearchData.age} onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>)}
                        {selectedOption === 'punishment' &&
                            (<fieldset>
                                <div className="m-1"> PUNISHMENT </div>
                                <div className="m-1">
                                    <label htmlFor="punishment" className="form-label">Punishment</label>
                                    <input id="punishment" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="punishment" type="text" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="m-1">
                                    <label htmlFor="dt" className="form-label">DT</label>
                                    <input id="dt" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="dt" type="text" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="m-1">
                                    <label htmlFor="aa" className="form-label">AA</label>
                                    <input id="aa" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="aa" type="text" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="m-1">
                                    <label htmlFor="offence" className="form-label">Offense</label>
                                    <input id="offence" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="offence" type="text" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="m-1">
                                    <label htmlFor="awarded_by" className="form-label">Awarded By</label>
                                    <input id="awarded_by" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="awarded_by" type="text" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>)}
                        {selectedOption === 'courses' &&
                            (
                                <fieldset>
                                    <div className="m-1">
                                        <label htmlFor="rank" className="form-label">Rank</label>
                                        <input id="rank" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="rank" type="text" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="m-1">
                                        <label htmlFor="name" className="form-label">Name</label>
                                        <input id="name" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="name" type="text" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="m-1">
                                        <label htmlFor="course" className="form-label">Course</label>
                                        <input id="course" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="course" type="text" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="m-1">
                                        <label htmlFor="year" className="form-label">Year </label>
                                        <input id="year" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="year" type="text" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="m-1">
                                        <label htmlFor="grading" className="form-label">Grading</label>
                                        <input id="grading" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="grading" type="text" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="m-1">
                                        <label htmlFor="part2" className="form-label">Part II Order No</label>
                                        <input id="part2" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="part2" type="text" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="m-1">
                                        <label htmlFor="remarks" className="form-label">Remarks</label>
                                        <input id="remarks" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="remarks" type="text" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>)}
                        {selectedOption === 'cadres' &&
                            (
                                <fieldset>
                                    <div className="m-1">
                                        <label htmlFor="rank" className="form-label">Rank</label>
                                        <input id="rank" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="rank" type="text" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="m-1">
                                        <label htmlFor="name" className="form-label">Name</label>
                                        <input id="name" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="name" type="text" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="m-1">
                                        <label htmlFor="cadre" className="form-label">Cadre</label>
                                        <input id="cadre" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="cadre" type="text" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="m-1">
                                        <label htmlFor="duration" className="form-label">Duration </label>
                                        <input id="duration" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="duration" type="text" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="m-1">
                                        <label htmlFor="result" className="form-label">Result</label>
                                        <input id="result" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="result" type="text" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="m-1">
                                        <label htmlFor="part2" className="form-label">Part II Order No</label>
                                        <input id="part2" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="part2" type="text" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="m-1">
                                        <label htmlFor="remarks" className="form-label">Remarks</label>
                                        <input id="remarks" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="remarks" type="text" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>)}
                        {selectedOption === 'eres' &&
                            (
                                <fieldset>
                                    <div className="m-1"> ERE's </div>
                                    <div className="m-1">
                                        <label htmlFor="ere_name" className="form-label">NAME OF ERE BN</label>
                                        <input id="ere_name" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="ere_name" type="text" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="m-1">
                                        <label htmlFor="duration_from" className="form-label">DURATION FROM</label>
                                        <input id="duration_from" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="duration_from" type="date" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="m-1">
                                        <label htmlFor="duration_to" className="form-label">DURATION TO</label>
                                        <input id="duration_to" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="duration_to" type="date" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="m-1">
                                        <label htmlFor="remarks" className="form-label">Remarks</label>
                                        <input id="remarks" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="remarks" type="text" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>)}
                        {selectedOption === 'loan' &&
                            (
                                <fieldset>
                                    <div className="m-1"> Loan Details </div>
                                    <div className="m-1">
                                        <label htmlFor="type_of_loan" className="form-label">Type Of Loan</label>
                                        <select className='form-control form-control-sm' name="type_of_loan" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData}>
                                            <option value="">Select One</option>
                                            {
                                                loanTypes.map((item, index) => {
                                                    return <option key={index} value={item.value}>{item.name}</option>
                                                })
                                            }
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="m-1">
                                        <label htmlFor="interest_rate" className="form-label">Interest Rate</label>
                                        <input id="interest_rate" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="interest_rate" type="text" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="m-1">
                                        <label htmlFor="emi" className="form-label">Emi</label>
                                        <input id="emi" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="emi" type="text" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="m-1">
                                        <label htmlFor="date" className="form-label">Date</label>
                                        <input id="date" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="date" type="date" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="m-1">
                                        <label htmlFor="no_of_years" className="form-label">No of Years</label>
                                        <input id="no_of_years" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="no_of_years" type="text" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="m-1">
                                        <label htmlFor="loaning_agency" className="form-label">Loading Agency</label>
                                        <input id="loading_agency" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="loading_agency" type="text" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="m-1">
                                        <label htmlFor="remarks" className="form-label">Remarks</label>
                                        <input id="remarks" className='form-control form-control-sm' name="remarks" type="text" onChange={handleAdvanceSearchData} />
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>)}
```

I wrote an an API to get data from the backend but the data is not rendering, and the data is not appearing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.